# Proof that this bounded sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I have this sequence that I'm not quite sure how to work with properly.
The exercise is the following:

Let $A_n$ $=$ $\frac {1}{n}$$(a_1+\dots+a_n)$.

(1) Prove that when $a_n$ $\rightarrow$ $a$, then also $A_n$ $\rightarrow$ $a$.

(2) Is the opposite also the case? ($A_n$ $\rightarrow$ $a$ $\Rightarrow$ $a_n$ $\rightarrow$ $a$)

So far i know that $a_n$ is bounded and that I can rewrite it to $A_n$ $=$ $\frac {\sum_{i=1}^n a_n}{n}$.

However, I do not know how to get to $a_n$ $\rightarrow$ $a$, $\Rightarrow$ $A_n$ $\rightarrow$ $a$ or (2) from this.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? How do I approach such a sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $a_n \rightarrow a$, so:

$\forall\varepsilon>0$ $\exists N>0$: $n>N\implies |a_n-a|<\varepsilon$

So rewrite $A_n$ as:

$A_n = \frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_N+a_{N+1}+...+a_n}{n}$

$A_n = \frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_N}{n} + \frac{a_{N+1}+...+a_n}{n}$

Now consider the difference $A_n-a$ and apply the definition of limit.

Hope this helps!